# How can I loop through a json object via `jq`?

Tags: json, shell, iteration, jq

I have a json object which is not an array.

```
{
  "affected-apps": {
    "result": "success",
    "outputs": {
      "affected_apps_array": [
        "logger",
        "aws-sdk-wrapper",
        "transaction",
        "deposit",
        "identity",
        "user",
        "core"
      ]
    }
  },
  "build-affected-apps": {
    "result": "success",
    "outputs": {}
  }
}
```

I'd like to loop through the object to find any `result` is not equal to `success`. I have searched a lot but only found how to do that if the json is an array. But my json a an object. How can I loop through the object for each key?

Comment: Can you please edit your sample json to include examples of both success and not success?

Comment: Please adhere to the [mcve] guidelines as much as possible. What is the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can use:

```
to_entries[] | select(.value.result != "success") | .key
```

This will yield the keys of the entries whose result is not "success". With your supplied JSON, it will yield no results (because all the steps were successful).

With the following JSON:

```
{
  "affected-apps": {
    "result": "success",
    "outputs": {
      "affected_apps_array": [
        "logger",
        "aws-sdk-wrapper",
        "transaction",
        "deposit",
        "identity",
        "user",
        "core"
      ]
    }
  },
  "build-affected-apps": {
    "result": "success",
    "outputs": {}
  },
  "load-affected-apps": {
    "result": "failure",
    "outputs": {}
  }
}
```

it will yield:

```
"load-affected-apps"
```